# Can we use Cloudkit for Android?

Tags: android, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

i am planing to make an app for android & iOS using cloud kit backend.
is there any way so cloud kit can works with android ? is it possible ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No; cloudKit is available for Apple devices only.

Comment: Dropbox is available for both.